# How to import java web application in to netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I downloaded a web application and deployed it in tomcat. Now, I'd like to make some changes to it, however, I've tried import project in Netbeans and Eclipse but that doesn't seem to work. Intially, the project was a war file it had opened in Netbeans but it doesn't seem to have the option to run.

Comment: Provide us much details as you can. This is more then insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Having a war file it's not enough to import project to Eclipse or Netbeans. WAR archive contains only compiled classes. What you need is source code. Look for sources for the web application.